# Download excel file from unix server to windows client

Tags: java, file, server, download, client

I recently started working on an app development using java. Purpose of the app is to process some api & output information in the form of excel file. JAR is located at server and runs when user send request at client(local machine).

The app generates excel file successfully but at the server location. I tried to using JAVA ChannelSftp approach to download from server to my local machine(client location) but it creates a new file at JAR location(i.e at Server location) instead of client location.
The code snippet is as below & this creates a file at JAR location with file name C:\Users\PFName-CFName_Co.xlsx

```
String SerDir=System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/";
String LocDir="C:\Users\";
String SerFC = SerDir+PFName+"-"+CFName+"_Co.xlsx";
String LocFC = LocDir+PFName+"-"+CFName+"_Cos.xlsx";
Session session = null;
ChannelSftp sftpChannel=null;
Channel channel = null;
JSch jsch = new JSch();
    try
    {
        session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);   
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking","no");
        session.setPassword(password);
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        sftpChannel =(ChannelSftp) channel;
        sftpChannel.cd(SerDir); 
        File file = new File(SerFC);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        BufferedInputStream bis;
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(sftpChannel.get(file.getName()));
        File newFile = new File(LocDir + file.getName());
        // Download file
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
        int readCount;
        while ((readCount = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            bos.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
    }
bis.close();
bos.close();
```

Please check & help me on how to download the file to client location(anywhere in c drive)